# How to Catch a "Trying to get property of non-object Error" in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I find the culprit of the following error in Laravel?

> Trying to get property of a non-object Error

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably coming from calling a method\property on a `null` object. So to fail early, you should use `Model::firstOrFail();` or `Model::findOrFail(ID);`. 
Other than that a `null` check can do it before you use, but it gets ugly if you have many `null` checks in your code.

`try {} catch (\Exception $e) {}` is also a way to catch an exception and handle it manually, but doing this in many places is again a lot of work.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is use a ternary operation on the model before accessing properties of that model like so
`$model = Model::find($id); $model ? $name = $model->name : null;` 
with this you can always be rest assured that a fatal throwable error would not be thrown if the model is not found. This also means you have to check if the variable name is not null before working with it like so `if(!is_null($name) { //do your stuff here}`